# Copy a row from one ListView to another

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

So this is my problem. I want to copy a specific row value from listView to another. For example;

```
listview1               listview2
Product   Price         Product   Price   QTY
Apple       5
Orange      5
```

then when I press "Apple"  it will copy to listview2, like this;

```
listview1               listview2
Product   Price         Product   Price   QTY
Apple       5           Apple       5
Orange      5
```

Also I'm using click event. TIA!

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page! - Why is it tagged 'Javascript'?

Comment: I'm so sorry. I'm new to stack overflow, I don't know how it works until now.

Comment: Welcome! The betterto follow the rules the more likely good answers will be. Here we'd like to see that Click event..

Comment: Winforms: `private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count < 1) return;
    var item = listView1.SelectedItems[0];
    listView2.Items.Add( (ListViewItem)  item.Clone());
}`

Comment: @TaW Sir you have just saved my life! Thanks Sir I learned so much today.

Answer (score 2):

TaW solved my problem. Here is the solution.

```
private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
   if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count < 1) return; 
   var item = listView1.SelectedItems[0]; 
   listView2.Items.Add( (ListViewItem) item.Clone()); 
}
```